# How to store output of a command run remotely in an array in perl

Tags: perl

I know this kind of question has been asked before, but I think I may have got lost trying to understand the examples provided in the responses. So I am asking it here again.

I have to collect list of files(absolute filenames only) from a particular folder on a remote machine.

On my Linux machine:

`opendir` - works locally. I want it to work remotely.

`use Net::FTP` - works but FTP disabled.

`use Net::SFTP` - could work but this Net::SFTP not installed.

I want some way to get this info considering that I have to make use of either sftp or ssh.

```
my $cmd = "ssh user\@host 'find x/y/z -type f'";
my @expectedOutputHere = system($cmd);
```

But `$expectedOutputHere` doesn't contain the list of files(as output).
Once I have the output I am planning to use File::Basename::basename to get absolute names. But how do I first collect the output in an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my @expectedOutputHere = `$cmd`;
```

The [manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) says: `The collected standard output of the command is returned`, `In list context, returns a list of lines`.

For `system()`, the manual specifies: `The return value is the exit status of the program`.

Comment: It's preferred to use the [`qx($cmd)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) syntax. It's easier to see than the back ticks, and allows a bit more flexibility in formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my $cmd = "ssh user\@host 'find x/y/z -type f'";
my @expectedOutputHere = `$cmd`;
chomp(@expectedOutputHere);
print Dumper @expectedOutputHere;
```